# Resize grouped buttons to size of text area?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making an interface where I need to have the following set up: button - textarea - button.

Using the input groups, the buttons do not scale to match the height of the textarea (as they do with "normal" form inputs)

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ty7N/2/)

The ideal markup:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn">                            
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">                            
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Semi-working markup (looks bad, buttons are small and surrounded by grey):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <button class="btn">                            
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">                            
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, the buttons stay small, and do not match the height of the textarea.

If you replaced the textarea with a text input, the buttons match (as shown in the BS3 docs)

Now, using an "input-group-addon" does make the prepended and appended items match up, but then they won't be buttons. Putting a button inside an "input-group-addon" tag just looks terrible.

So, is there a way to get the buttons to match the height of the textarea?

Comment: in the fiddle I see, the button matches the height of the textarea ?

Comment: Fixed the link! (also, if you noticed that code, it wasn't a button :P)

Comment: So what the link showed before wasn't right? It looked like that was what you were searching for ...

Comment: JiFus - read my question. The Fiddle you saw was what "kind of" works i.e. it is not what I want, as it did not use buttons. The link now is correct and shows my mark up and the fact that buttons do not match the height of the text area. Re-read my question and check the new link as it is all clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example can help:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.input-arreglo-group{
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
.input-arreglo{
    margin-top: 0px; 
    height: calc(100% + 15px); 
    border-top-left-radius: 0px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="proyecto_descripcion">Descripción</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" style="resize:vertical;" rows="7" id="proyecto_descripcion" name="proyecto_descripcion" placeholder="Descripción del Proyecto"></textarea>
        <div class="input-group-addon input-arreglo-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger input-arreglo">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Al cambiar el tamaño de textarea el button se adapta al tamaño.

Comment: @David [calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) does not work in some browser.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution that may work for you. I think the problem is that these are custom font icons inserted with a `:before` class. So they won't respond to `height` you'll need to size them with `font-size:`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ty7N/4/)**

The only issue I see here is that you're going to have to hard code them to align correctly with your input box (i've used em's out of preference). I've added a few classes to make things easy and not overwrite the bootstrap css.

HTML:

```
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn">                            
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open custom-eye"></span>
       </button>
     </span>
     <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3"></textarea>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-danger">                            
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove custom-remove"></span>
       </button>
     </span>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-control {height: 5.25em}

.custom-eye {font-size: 4em;}

.custom-remove {font-size: 4em;}
```

Comment: I'm not actually worried about the glyphicon size, sorry if I didn't mention that. I just want the button element to match the text area height.

Comment: @MrPablo so you're looking for something more like [http://jsfiddle.net/3Ty7N/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ty7N/5/)?

Comment: Yes, but with the icons central. I fixed it by assigning a height of 4em's to the button and textarea :)